# how to create the download blob link in oracle apex 5.2

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have created an interactive report in oracle apex 5.1 in which I have 4 columns. One of those columns is blob column named as `doc_pic`. I made it download blob type column and fill all the requirements, IE: MIME type, file name, last updated, primary key 1 according to the view from where it belong.

In that view I have multiple tables and most of them contain composite primary key which is based on `number` and `varchar2` columns. The problem is when I run the page it gives me  **no data found error** but when I hide that column report is running fine.

I tried created it by making unique id through `rownum` but still it is giving the same error.
I also tried to make a unique column by concatenating it with another column which is varchar2 but, then it gave me error

> **ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error**

Somebody please tell me where I am going wrong in creating a download blob link. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use the BLOB column directly in IR's query. Instead of it, use this:

```
select column_list_here,
       dbms_lob.getlength(doc_pic) doc_pic     --> this
from your_table
...
```

The rest should be easy.

Comment: after using that should I follow the same procedure by select download blob type and fulfilling its requirement?

Comment: Yes; that's why I said that it should be easy :)